# Как получить датафрейм на основе названий столбцов, если встречаются столбцы с одинаковым именем?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5, dataframe

У меня есть матрица и я хотел бы научится собирать срез датафрейма на основе названия столбцов по какой-нибудь маске. Например хочу получить датафрейм из столбцов, в названии которых стоит например `1`. 
Вот мой код ниже:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://st.storeland.ru/6/2418/067/demo.csv', sep=',', index_col=-1)
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('unnamed', case=False)].T
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.contains('1')]
```

Я ожидал получить столбцы с названием `1`, а получаю столбцы с названием `-1`.
Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Так какие все-таки столбцы вы хотите получить? `"-1"` - тоже содержит `"1"`

Comment: @MaxU В примере он выводит только `-1`, но не выводит `1`.  Хочу получить чистые `1`. ну и конечно понять свою ошибку синтаксиса, чтобы составлять разные условия, например выводить столбцы с названием `0` и `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала надо разобраться из каких значений состоят столбцы:

```
In [92]: df.columns
Out[92]: Int64Index([0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1], dtype='int64', name='CLASS')
```

В вашем случае это *целые* числа, а не *строки*.

Чтобы выбрать все столбцы с наименованием `1`:

```
In [93]: df.loc[:, df.columns == 1]
Out[93]:
CLASS         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
2      0.107562 -0.030342  0.094460  0.097331  0.287434 -0.102189 -0.061600
3      0.000000  0.056551  0.100908  0.107267  0.045314  0.020571 -0.141625
4      0.069416  0.120947  0.063056  0.079598  0.208886  0.110355  0.122441
5      0.213758  0.157801  0.139664  0.462731  0.276140 -0.051725 -0.033541
6      0.167404  0.198542  0.121033  0.126135  0.315803 -0.133429 -0.141595
7      0.137428  0.144441  0.144518  0.060192  0.141858  0.044725 -0.050224
8     -0.048976 -0.051127 -0.014204 -0.004287  0.209531 -0.083125  0.117327
..          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
21     0.029495 -0.055341  0.063740  0.008971 -0.192746  0.109942  0.213453
22     0.020571  0.034027  0.161940  0.002467 -0.206805  0.000000  0.019226
23    -0.141625 -0.050704 -0.247434  0.003421 -0.028701  0.019226  0.000000
24     0.125518 -0.011295  0.028568  0.339476  0.180785 -0.094717 -0.028576
25     0.110515  0.016067  0.099358  0.274346  0.494111 -0.181894 -0.017986
26     0.023603  0.068043  0.200504  0.087012  0.111817  0.119159 -0.214210
27     0.289351  0.217753  0.096566  0.150651  0.001768  0.106498  0.017062

[26 rows x 7 columns]
```

PS не советую использовать неуникальные имена столбцов или значения индексов - вы сможете обращаться к таким столбцам или индексам только при помощи позиционного "accessor" [DataFrame.iloc[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) или при помощи `boolean indexing`. Т.е. вы лишаете себя возможности простого и удобного доступа по имени столбца / значению индекса.

---

> а если это будут строки, а не числа, как использовать в этом случае
>   contains?

используя тот же принцип:

```
In [94]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

In [95]: df.columns
Out[95]:
Index(['0', '1', '-1', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1',
       '1', '-1', '-1', '0', '-1'],
      dtype='object', name='CLASS')

In [96]: df.loc[:, df.columns == '1']
Out[96]:
CLASS         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
2      0.107562 -0.030342  0.094460  0.097331  0.287434 -0.102189 -0.061600
3      0.000000  0.056551  0.100908  0.107267  0.045314  0.020571 -0.141625
4      0.069416  0.120947  0.063056  0.079598  0.208886  0.110355  0.122441
5      0.213758  0.157801  0.139664  0.462731  0.276140 -0.051725 -0.033541
6      0.167404  0.198542  0.121033  0.126135  0.315803 -0.133429 -0.141595
7      0.137428  0.144441  0.144518  0.060192  0.141858  0.044725 -0.050224
8     -0.048976 -0.051127 -0.014204 -0.004287  0.209531 -0.083125  0.117327
..          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
21     0.029495 -0.055341  0.063740  0.008971 -0.192746  0.109942  0.213453
22     0.020571  0.034027  0.161940  0.002467 -0.206805  0.000000  0.019226
23    -0.141625 -0.050704 -0.247434  0.003421 -0.028701  0.019226  0.000000
24     0.125518 -0.011295  0.028568  0.339476  0.180785 -0.094717 -0.028576
25     0.110515  0.016067  0.099358  0.274346  0.494111 -0.181894 -0.017986
26     0.023603  0.068043  0.200504  0.087012  0.111817  0.119159 -0.214210
27     0.289351  0.217753  0.096566  0.150651  0.001768  0.106498  0.017062

[26 rows x 7 columns]

In [97]: df.columns.str.contains('1')
Out[97]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Comment: а если это будут строки, а не числа, как использовать в этом случае contains?